# Disqus "Show Comments" Button Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, disqus, pelican

I have a website that uses Disqus for comments.  I use a button to hide the comments.  The user must click the "2 Comments" button to see the comments:

[image: Must Click Button to Show Comments]

For blog posts with Zero comments, Disqus loads.

If I try to click a button on a site with comments, nothing happens.

For example - try to click the "2 comments" button.
https://john.soban.ski/m30-linux.html#disqus_thread

I use the following code:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    var disqus = 'freshlex';
                    var disqus_shortname = 'freshlex';
                    var disqus_identifier = '/m30-linux.html';
                    var disqus_url = 'https://john.soban.ski/m30-linux.html';
                </script>
                <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the comments.</noscript>
                <section class="post-comments">
                        <a id="show-disqus" class="post-comments-activate" data-disqus-identifier="/m30-linux.html" >Show Comments</a>
                    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
                </section>
```

and

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var disqus_shortname = 'freshlex';
    (function () {
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: Dev console is your friend: "Uncaught ReferenceError: hljs is not defined `hljs.highlightBlock(e);` - line 116 in your scripts.js. My guess is your JS is failing here and not getting to the JS to load Disqus.

Comment: @disinfor - That's it!!! I can't post on any blog post I have with code snippets.  The ones without code snippets work fine.  Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who have a similar "button doesn't work issue:"

Go to Chrome's Developer tools, look for a red triangle, click it and read the issue

I have [a theme](https://john.soban.ski/theme/js/script.js) that calls [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/).  I did not load highlight.js and that killed all the following scripts, including my Disqus script.

I needed to add the CDN reference to my web page HTML.

So I added:

```bash
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.7.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

And that fixed it.